# Convert Windows Batch Script to Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

I have the following Windows batch script (.bat file). I would like to convert this into a Linux shell script.  Please help...

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)

:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +v

for -f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.- A in ('Is-I -B TACOS_*'); do (
    getmonth B
    mv -iv TACOS*_*A-B-C*_*D-E-F_AST.csv TACOS_A!mon!C_DEF.csv
)


:getmonth
if "$1" equ "Jan" then mon=01
if "$1" equ "Feb" then mon=02
if "$1" equ "Mar" then mon=03
if "$1" equ "Apr" then mon=04
if "$1" equ "May" then mon=05
if "$1" equ "Jun" then mon=06
if "$1" equ "Jul" then mon=07
if "$1" equ "Aug" then mon=08
if "$1" equ "Sep" then mon=09
if "$1" equ "Oct" then mon=10
if "$1" equ "Nov" then mon=11
if "$1" equ "Dec" then mon=12
goto :eof
```

---

here is what i have tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash
set +v

for -f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.- A in ('Is-I -B TACOS_*'); do (
    getmonth B
    mv -iv TACOS*_*A-B-C*_*D-E-F_AST.csv TACOS_A!mon!C_DEF.csv
)


:getmonth
if "$1" equ "Jan" then mon=01
if "$1" equ "Feb" then mon=02
if "$1" equ "Mar" then mon=03
if "$1" equ "Apr" then mon=04
if "$1" equ "May" then mon=05
if "$1" equ "Jun" then mon=06
if "$1" equ "Jul" then mon=07
if "$1" equ "Aug" then mon=08
if "$1" equ "Sep" then mon=09
if "$1" equ "Oct" then mon=10
if "$1" equ "Nov" then mon=11
if "$1" equ "Dec" then mon=12
goto :eof
```

Comment: i have no clue about linux shell script... My managers has given me 3 hours to submit the script in shell....

Comment: That seems an unrealistic deadline if you haven't got any knowledge about it...

Comment: The Linux Documentation project has a couple of introductions to scripting in the Bash shell. [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html) and [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html)

Comment: @GolezTrol Please see the code below i have tried to convert...

Comment: You need to figure out what the batch file is doing, and then figure out how to do that in your Linux shell (most likely *bash*).  You can't just do a line-by-line replacement of slashes to dash and `%` to `$` and expect it to work...  If you can't tell what the batch script is doing just by running it, then from the Windows command line type `help for` and `help set` and read those help pages.  Also, you meant `ls -l`, not `Is-I`... but what you really want is just `ls` without `-l`.

Comment: Anyway, the batch file is listing all files in a directory that begin with `TACOS_`.  Then it splits each filename into pieces delimited by any of these characters: `_.-`.  That gives 7 pieces of the filename.  It's replacing the 3rd piece, which is apparently a month name, with a number representing the month.  The 2nd piece is in the variable `%%A`, the 3rd in `%%B` (and later in `!mon!`), the 4th in `%%C`, and so on.  And you can see it uses these pieces to construct a new filename that it then uses to rename each file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not great at Bash (I've tried to convert before; ended up turning it into an exe, asking people to get [Wine Compatibility layer](http://winehq.org)) but I believe I know part of your problem. You cannot use labels (:example) and goto, (goto example) in bash scripting. You have to use functions. In your case:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +v

for -f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.- A in ('Is-I -B TACOS_*'); do (
    getmonth() B
    mv -iv TACOS*_*A-B-C*_*D-E-F_AST.csv TACOS_A!mon!C_DEF.csv
)


function getmonth()
{
if "$1" equ "Jan" then mon=01
if "$1" equ "Feb" then mon=02
if "$1" equ "Mar" then mon=03
if "$1" equ "Apr" then mon=04
if "$1" equ "May" then mon=05
if "$1" equ "Jun" then mon=06
if "$1" equ "Jul" then mon=07
if "$1" equ "Aug" then mon=08
if "$1" equ "Sep" then mon=09
if "$1" equ "Oct" then mon=10
if "$1" equ "Nov" then mon=11
if "$1" equ "Dec" then mon=12
eof()
}
```

[Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html) is a great guide to converting Batch to Shell. It hasn't helped me a lot, but I think you'll find it useful.

Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this program?

Comment: Helpful link, thanks.. The batch file example is pretty biassed (and it probably could be better). Personally, I like to use a combination of `call :target`, `setlocal` and `goto  :eof` to sandbox my Batch "functions". However, thee comparison tables are useful. I'll make use of those when I get around to converting one of my more complex dev scripts.